# How to play SWF file faster in C#

Tags: c#, axshockwaveflash

Is there a way to alter fps using axShockwaveFlash control?

I was thinking I could use a timer and go to next frame faster but it severely affects the flow of the sound. I don't want to skip frames but I would like to play them fast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting to speed up the video without affecting the sound, or did the timer solution just make the sound aggressively awful?

Comment: it plays at 16 fps presently would like to fast forward around 25  because we are manually going through them to upgrading our old university physics simulations and there are tons of them.. my team would like to watch the whole thing faster as mostly profs speak slowly...

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, so let me explain a bit more.  If you are hoping to speed up the video without affecting the sound, you're in for a very rough time.  The two are inextricably linked in the original object, so even in the best of times you're going to get some chipmunk-sounding mess going on.  Are you hearing that, or are you hearing things like popping, snapping, cracking, and other audio disturbances that make it impossible to listen to?